# BottomNavigationBar() and BottomNavigationBarItem() changes there colors to white if its items are more than 3, automatically

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I've a BottomNavigationBar() in my flutter app.

It works normally when I've 3 BottomNavigationBarItem()s.

But as soon as I add the fourth BottomNavigationBarItem(), the color of my bar and its items changes to white, which is uninvited.

Here is the screenshot of the app with three items

[image]

and this one is with four.

[image]

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.category),
        title: Text('categoris'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
        title: Text('Wishlist'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket),
        title: Text('Bag'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
        title: Text('Profile'),
      ),
    ],
  ), ``
```

Please guide me what shall I do to overcome this. As I'm new to flutter, your guidance will be of much help.

Comment: Detailed documented answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72264249/12695188

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation for [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html), if there more then three BottomNavigationBarItems then BottomNavigationBarType.shifting type is used.

This shifting type renders all items in white if selectedItemColor is null.

You will need to add selectedColor property for BottomNavigationBar widget to change this behavior as below:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      //Selected items color gives color to the BottomNavigationBarItem's title widget, which is currently selected
      selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
      //Selected icons theme gives icon theme the BottomNavigationBarItem's icon widget, which is currently selected
      selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
        color: Colors.blue,
        opacity: 1.0,
        size: 30.0
      ),
      //unselected items color gives color to the BottomNavigationBarItem's title widget, which is currently unselected
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
      //unselected icons theme gives icon theme the BottomNavigationBarItem's icon widget, which is currently unselected
      unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.black,
            opacity: 1.0,
            size: 30.0
      ),
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.category),
          title: Text('categoris'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
          title: Text('Wishlist'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket),
          title: Text('Bag'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          title: Text('Profile'),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But can you please tell me why it worked? Cause for three items it was working all right.

Comment: Please don't just copy paste solutions/fixes. A little brief description would be nice.

Comment: You can also add `backgroundColor: context.theme.navigationColor` to each `BottomNavigationBarItem()` if you need NavigationBar's background color other than white