# Flutter BottomNavigationBar colors changes to transparent after adding more than 3 items

Tags: flutter

**It's really weird.** Adding more than 3 `BottomNavigationBarItem`s changes the default icon and background colors of `BottomNavigationBar` to transparent.

Why is that?

P.S, everything works just fine with 2 or 3 items.

```
class BottomNavigationTabs extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomNavigationTabs({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: child,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add), label: 'Create'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite), label: 'Favorite'),
          // BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: 'Profile'), // <-- uncomment transparent the whole bottomNavigationBar
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) documentation:

> The bottom navigation bar's type changes how its items are displayed.
> If not specified, then it's automatically set to
> [BottomNavigationBarType.fixed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBarType.html) when there are less than four items, **and
> [BottomNavigationBarType.shifting](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBarType.html) otherwise.**
>
> ...
>
> BottomNavigationBarType.shifting, the default when there are four or
> more items. **If selectedItemColor is null, all items are rendered in white.**

### Two solutions

1. The most simplest solution will be keeping the `BottomNavigationBar` type as `fixed` for more than three items.

`type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed`.

2. The second solution, will be editing the `selectedItemColor` color.

Answer (score 0):

Set properties of BottomNavigationBar like

```
fixedColor: Colors.red, //Selected Icon color. Overrides primary Color

//TextStyles
showUnselectedLabels: true,
unselectedLabelStyle:
   const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
selectedLabelStyle:
   const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),

//Icon
unselectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.grey),
selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.red),
```

Comment: Sharing a simpler solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/72264249/12695188, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those who use themes - you need to set two properties (unselectedItemColor and selectedItemColor):

```
  static ThemeData light() {
  return ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light,

  bottomNavigationBarTheme: const BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.black45,
    selectedItemColor: Color.fromRGBO(238, 129, 39, 1.0),
  ),
  
  textTheme: lightTextTheme,
);}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you must add background color for every one item

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This happens if you have not specified the type of BottomNavigationBar
It do not cause any problem if you have just 3 items
But if items are more than 3, you have to specify the type of BottomNavigationBar

```
type: BottonNavigationBarType.fixed
```

Use fixed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).